# Geoserver on EC2 - Can't get to web admin page after restarting EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgis, geoserver

I've set up a GeoServer connected to a postGIS db, all running on an EC2. I'm able to connect and add layers from the PostGIS db and pull everything as WMS/WFS just fine. My problem comes in when I add security (removing anonymous authentication and adding two new roles to the server - a read only and a write tied to the database workspace). Everything still works fine with these security settings. I can stop and start the GeoServer just fine. The problem comes when I **stop and start the EC2**.

After stopping the EC2, I can restart it (tied to the same elastic IP), remote into it to start the GeoServer. Once started, if I attempt to connect to the Geoserver web admin page, I receive a browser error:

> This page isn't working
>
> [EC2 Public DNS (IPv4)] redirected you too many times
>
> Try clearing your cookies.
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Without modifying any of the security settings I did, I could stop and start the EC2 and things re-connected just fine. I'm not sure what is causing this hang up.

The WFS/WMS services are still running and working just fine. I just need to get to the administration level of GeoServer but something about restarting the EC2 has locked me out. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you sure your Geoserver service started on EC2 after restart?

Comment: Yea, manually connected to the EC2 and started Geoserver. Also, I can pull features still via WFS. Just can't get to the admin page!

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution to this issue? I can usually get around it by visiting the `/geoserver/j_spring_security_check` url, but it's very annoying!